# If a machine recognizes language L, can it also recognize L*?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata

This is a homework question. Suppose the only accept state is the start state. My rationale for this is that L* is just the concatenations of L, so if all strings in L are accepted, then all strings in L* will be accepted as well. One problem I see with this is that a machine can only accept one language, so it might be problematic...

Comment: Is your real question, "does an automaton for $L^*$ accept all words from $L$"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One problem I see with this is that a machine can only accept one language, so it might be problematic.

You are answering your own question: by definition¹, any given automaton accepts $L$ *and* $L^*$ if and only if $L = L^*$. This can happen -- examples include $L = \{ \varepsilon \}$ and $L = \Sigma^*$, for instance, but not as a rule.

It is not clear from your question if you understand the acceptance criterion of finite automata. The automaton has to be in a final state *after reading the whole input*, not in the beginning or at any time.

---

1. The language accepted by automaton $A$ is uniquely defined to be the set of words $w$ for which $A(w)$ is (an) accepting (computation).

Comment: So the answer to the question is: **yes**, if a (finite state) machine recognizes some language $L$, it *can* also recognize $L^*$.

Comment: @A.Schulz. ... in *some* situations, yes.